# PHP Class instanced twice even with Singleton design pattern

Tags: php, singleton, instance

Class:

```
if( ! class_exists('MY_CLASS') ) :

class MY_CLASS {

    private static $_instance = null;


    private static $counter = 0;


    private function __construct() {

        self::$counter++;

        // Do stuff here.

        echo "instances: " . self::$counter . "<br>";
    }

    // Other functions here

    public static function instance() {

        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {

            self::$_instance = new MY_CLASS();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}


function ctp() {
    return MY_CLASS::instance();
}

// initialize
ctp();

endif; // class_exists check
```

The $counter is always 2. I've checked and the function `instance()` enters the if condition `is_null( self::$_instance )` twice.

Really not being able to make this class only be instanced once. Please help.

Comment: class is a reserved word; you can't name your class CLASS... no complaints from your editor? More generally, you should try to be consistent in naming your variables / objects, e.g. I see you have two static variables, one with underscore, and one without. Have a look at [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) for some inspiration.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the name of the class to be clearer. I don't have it as CLASS. I'm sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found what was causing the problem.

So in `My_Class` I had:

```
function includes() {

    require_once( 'path-to-second-class.php' );

    // several other requires
}

private function init() {

    // various class instantiations « new Class_Name() », but not for Second_Class
}
```

And in second-class.php I had

```
class Second_Class {

    $taxs = array();

    function __construct() {

        $this->taxs = ctp()->get_ctp_taxs();        // which returns Main_Class->$taxs

        // do other stuff
    }

    function do_stuff() {

        foreach( $this->taxs as $tax_name => $tax_object ) {

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}

new Second_Class();
```

This, for some reason that I tbh don't know, doesn't work so I changed it to:

`My_Class`:

```
function includes() {

    require_once( 'path-to-second-class.php' );

    // several other requires
}

private function init() {

    // same other instantiations

    new Second_Class();
}
```

And in second-class.php I now have:

```
class Second_Class {

    function __construct() {

        // do same other stuff
    }

    function do_stuff() {

        foreach( ctp()->get_ctp_taxs() as $tax_name => $tax_object ) {

            // do stuff

        }
    }
}
```